# What is the better way of git clone private repos?

Tags: git, github, ssh

Previously SSH was used to `git clone` and `push` with keys but what if the default port `22` is blocked or cloning in a proxy and in a no proxy environment.

What is the better way of cloning in the Python script?

Answer (score 2):

Try Adding This:

```
Host github.com
Hostname ssh.github.com
Port 443
User git
```

Source: [Github](https://help.github.com/articles/using-ssh-over-the-https-port)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

If port 22 is blocked, you use HTTP protocol.

```
git clone http://github.com/user_name/repo
```

Comment: What if there is personal access tokens to clone with https:// , but i dont want user prompts to authenticate.

Answer (score 0):

At Github you can use host ssh.github.com port 443:

```
git clone ssh://git@ssh.github.com:443/user/repo.git
```

See the [docs](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/troubleshooting-ssh/using-ssh-over-the-https-port).